# IntelliJ Code Completion List Keeps Reloading

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.3. Recently, I noticed that, frequently, my code completion list continually disappears and reloads. Appears for approximately 1 second, then disappears and reloads, then the cycle repeats.

I am not sure if this is relevant, but I am using Kotlin and Arrow-kt.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA and provide the logs: Help | Compress Logs and Show in ... See if the issue persists in https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2019.3+latest+builds.

Answer (score 1):

Just update to Kotlin 1.3.72. In this release this bug was fixed.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-37144